# Speed up evaluation of array of functions at discrete points

Tags: performance-tuning

I have large array of some functions (mainly polynomials). I need to evaluate them at a set of discrete points. Is there any faster way than this? ParallelTable is not helping since this part of code is already inside parallel loop.

```
First[
  Timing[
    Table[
      Table[
        i/t^3 + Sqrt[j]*Sin[t] + i*j*s^12 - j*Cos[t*s], 
        {i, 1, 300}, {j, 1, 300}], 
      {t, Table[RandomReal[], {10}]}, {s, Table[RandomReal[], {10}]}]]]
```

This piece of code returns 1.279 s on my i5 4570.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs on my computer at about the same speed as your, namely `1.25 sec`.  However, with four processors my computer provides almost a factor of four speed-up with ParallelTable, applied to the outer loops.

```
First[Timing[ParallelTable[Table[i/t^3 + Sqrt[j]*Sin[t] + i*j*s^12 - j*Cos[t*s], 
{i, 1, 300}, {j, 1, 300}], {t, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]}, {s, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]}]]]
(* 0.34375 *)
```

Applying `ParallelTable` to the inner loops is counterproductive, because the parallel overhead more than offsets the savings from parallelization.  I had hoped that moving some function evaluations out of the inner loops would increase the speed, but it does not.

```
First[Timing[ParallelTable[cts = Cos[t*s]; s12 = s^12; st = Sin[t]; 
    Table[i/t^3 + Sqrt[j]*st + i*j*s12 - j*cts, {i, 1, 300}, {j, 1, 300}], 
    {t, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]}, {s, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]}]]]
(* 0.359375 *)
```

Incidentally, replacing `Table[RandomReal[], {10}]` by `RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]` has no noticeable impact on speed, as would be expected.  It just seemed cleaner too me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the listability of the involved functions can speed the inner part of the loop quite a bit! The deeper indices `i` and `j` are also the most important to optimize, since `t` and `s` only run over 10 values each.

First, my timings of OP and bbgodfrey (quad-core MacBook Pro i7):

```
s1 = RandomReal[{0,1}, 10];
t1 = RandomReal[{0,1}, 10];

(* OP *)
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[Table[
    i/t^3 + Sqrt[j]*Sin[t] + i*j*s^12 - j*Cos[t*s], {i, 1, 300}, {j, 
     1, 300}], {t, t1}, {s, s1}]]]
(* 2.820927 *)

(* bbgodfrey *)
First[AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[cts = Cos[t*s]; s12 = s^12; st = Sin[t]; 
    Table[i/t^3 + Sqrt[j]*st + i*j*s12 - j*cts, {i, 1, 300}, {j, 1, 300}], 
    {t, t1}, {s, s1}]]]
(* 1.101128 *)
```

The last timing is from running bbgodfrey's code a second time, so that it is not penalized from the time it takes to launch the parallell kernels.

Here is my suggestion:

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[
  jvec = N@Range[300];
  sqrtjvec = Sqrt[jvec];
  Table[
   indepOfi = sqrtjvec*Sin[t] - jvec*Cos[t*s];
   Table[
    i/t^3 + i*jvec*s^12 + indepOfi
    , {i, 1, 300}
    ]
   , {t, t1}
   , {s, s1}
   ]
  ]
 ]
(* 0.296427 *)
```

My solution uses vectorized operations over the innermost index `j`, and also the fact that `Sqrt` is usually faster for machine-precision input, which is what we will end up with anyway since `t` and `s` are machine precision. It also makes a difference that I pull `indepOfi` out of the inner `Table`, as bbgodfrey expected.

Probably it does not make sense to use a `ParallelTable` with my solution, as the overhead would swallow the gains from vectorization. There might be ways to vectorize over other dimensions here as well, and build up the answer using `Outer` or similar, but probably only vectorizing over the larger dimensions `i` and `j` is worth it.