# Efficiently create an array of values of a function

Tags: list-manipulation, packed-arrays

I have a function of four arguments, and I would like to have its values on the four-dimensional grid in an array.  What is the most efficient way to produce this array, and how do I make it packed?

Let's say the function is

```
f[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_] = Exp[ - (x1 - x2 + x3)^2 - (x2 + x3-x4)^2 ];
```

And I want to compute its values on the grid defined by (for all four variables)

```
dX = .25; xList = Range[ -5. , 5. , dX ];
```

So the best I could come up with was

```
A = Outer[ f , # , # , # , # ]& @ xList
```

This, unfortunately, takes quite a time to complete even for the grid having `41^4` elements while I would be happy to have a larger grid.  Moreover, the produced array `A` is not packed.  Is there a way to make the computation faster and pack the produced array?

Comment: takes 12s on my laptop, if you do not loop over this that seems reasonable. In what context you you use this function?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132398/speed-up-evaluation-of-array-of-functions-at-discrete-points/132424#132424) can be used?

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101696/fast-evaluation-of-a-function-in-many-points/101708#101708) is more relevant, as your function is listable and similar to the linked function.

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 yep, it takes approximately the same time on mine, so 'takes quite a time' perhaps is not the best wording for my problem.  The first issue here is that if I run, say, `RandomReal` to generate an array of the same size, it takes about 500 times less time. Second is a memory issue: the procedure scales with the size of the array to the extent that after a certain size the array does not fit into my RAM. That's why I asked about packing.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer thanks a lot for the linked questions, compiling the function helped me to improve the performance.