# Why does summation over list elements are very slow compared to direct numbers?

Tags: summation

Here I will provide a simple example of what I mean. Using `ParallelSum` with direct numbers is very fast as here

```
     Module[{stp = 0.002}, 
      ParallelSum[stp^2 Sin[x y]^2, {x, -3., 3., stp}, {y, -3., 3., 
        stp}]] // AbsoluteTiming

 {5.01413, 16.4759}
```

Now assume that I have a random list of `{x, y}` and would like to perform the `ParallelSum` form the list as follows:
the random list is in the form

```
Module[{stp = 0.002}, 
 listF = Flatten[
    ParallelTable[{x, y}, {x, -3., 3., stp}, {y, -3., 3., stp}], 1];]
```

and then

```
Module[{stp = 0.002}, 
  Sum[stp^2 Sin[listF[[i, 1]] listF[[i, 2]]]^2, {i, 
    Length[listF]}]] // AbsoluteTiming

 {15.2268, 16.4759}
```

as you can see it is 3 times slower now?!

**Note:** if I use `ParallelSum` in the last part instead of `Sum` it is even much more slower.

Comment: If you often need to optimize operations like this, you should dive into vectorized operations and packed arrays. They can make orders of magnitude difference, compared to parallelization which is less than linear in the nr of kernels (less because of overhead).

Comment: any links please for such operations?

Comment: Absolutely! Leonid Shifrin's answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) is a good place to start. The other answers are of course also informative. Any answer provided by @ciao is in my opinion very often examples of this practice.

Comment: I use some vectorization ideas in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132398/speed-up-evaluation-of-array-of-functions-at-discrete-points/132424#132424)

Answer (score 1):

By using a combination of [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) we can speed up the sum quite a bit:

```
With[{stp = 0.002},
  listF = Tuples[Range[-3., 3., stp], 2];
  stp^2 * Total[Sin[#[[1]] * #[[2]]]^2 & /@ listF] // AbsoluteTiming]

(*    {2.03412, 16.4759}    *)
```

I would assume that `Sum` assumes that the argument might depend on the index `i` in a way that prevents certain optimizations. `Map`, on the other hand, does away with the index, which allows for speedier execution in general.